# Connect to Oracle Database in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to test Oracle Database in my C# windows application. I have created a workspace on Oracle Application Express. I have also created DNS and the connection is formed successfully.

On successful connection I have written a code to get the list of tables.

```
schemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

This code snippet successfully returns the list the tables. Now when I try to read the data from EMP table I receive below error:

> ERROR [42S02] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00903: invalid table name

[image: Schema and Table]

Query to retrieve the data from EMP table

queryString: "Select * from [EMP];"

```
 using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
                da.Fill(fillGridDt);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Apex workspace has nothing to do with that; it is the database user (schema) that matters. OK, you return list of tables, but can't select anything from EMP table - could you post a command you used?

Comment: I have updated my question with code that i have used to get table data

Comment: In my application I am giving 2 options to the user
Option 1: Select table name from list of tables
Option 2: Type the query
In case of Option 1; i.e. table selection; I selected EMP table. In that case i receive invalid table name error.
But when I select Option 2: Select * from EMP Query gets executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.
It was throwing the error invalid table name as i was using [] brackets with table name.
i.e. Select * from [EMP]
I tried the query with Select * from EMP; and now it works